# iotop command for checking IO usage at the android device

Tags: database

I've checked IO usage at Android device using "iotop" command as
"iotop -P -d 60 -n 1 -s write -m 10 -a"

The propose of this, I want to know the 1 row of databases IO usage.
I've wrote databases using bulk. The result of data are something strange.

For example,

1. 65446 rows of databases - 483612KiB (checked by iotop) = 1row is about 7.3KiB
2. 72 rows databases - 100KiB = 1row is about 1.38KiB

The gap is very big. Is it right to find out 1 row database IO usage using "iotop" ?
Can you give me some advise?

Thanks.